# Why this chunk reading code doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, chunks

I don't know why, but my chunked upload doesn't work. The first chunk which is read is probably right, but the following chunks only contain `0`.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gibt die Bytesequenz des angeforderten Chunks zurück
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chunkNumber">Die Position des Chunks im Array</param>
    /// <returns>Die Bytesequenz des angeforderten Chunks</returns>
    byte[] FileToChunk(int chunkNumber)
    {
        byte[] chunkBuffer = new byte[chunkSize];
        FileStream fileStream = new
             FileStream( "C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Downloads\\Prog\\UnityAssets\\start.unitypackage" 
                              , FileMode.Open
                              , FileAccess.Read
                              );
        fileStream.Seek((chunkNumber - 1) * chunkSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        while (fileStream.Read(chunkBuffer, 0, chunkBuffer.Length) > 0);
        if (    fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length 
             && fileStream.Position != fileStream.Position - 1 
           )
              fileStream.Close();
        return chunkBuffer;
    }
```

So, the number of the chunk which should be extracted is passed as argument, and with
`fileStream.Seek()` I want to go the position of the chunk which is asked. As I already said, the first call of this method returns a probably working chunk, but all other calls return `Byte[]` - arrays filled with `0`. The `chunkSize` is 256kB (1024*256 bytes) and the file I want to read has a size of ~ 11 MB (= 11000kB), so it should be split into `(int)Math.Ceiling((double)(file.fileSize / chunkSize))` parts.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`FileStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of bytes read. So the following loop:

```
while (fileStream.Read(chunkBuffer, 0, chunkBuffer.Length) > 0);
```

will run until the end of stream. To read the chunk you want you should call the method just once:

```
fileStream.Read(chunkBuffer, 0, chunkBuffer.Length);
```

Also, consider using the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement instead of manually closing the file.